# Haskell - dealing with recursive functions that branch out

Tags: haskell, recursion

So I am rather new to Haskell and I am having a lot of a trouble not thinking imperatively. And I need to create a recursive function that branches out. Let me explain what I mean.

My function takes some tuple and 3 integers (a, b, c). If some conditions are met, the function should stop. Otherwise, the function calculates the new values of (a, b, c), calculates a list based on the elements of the tuple, and call itself for each element of the list.

For now, the function looks something like this (I have omitted the elements of the tuple since it doesn't matter):

```
function :: () -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
function someTuple a0 b0 c0
    | someCondition = [(a0, b0, d0)]
    | otherwise = [function () a1 b1 c1 | x <- someList]
    where a1 = ...
          b1 = ...
          c1 = ...
          someList = ...
```

The problem (as you can probably tell) is, that the function only returns the numbers computed on one branch of the recursion.

Now, the only thing I REALLY need are the 3 new numbers that are computed each time the function is called. I an ideal world (or in an imperative language), I could use some gimmick like appending the numbers to a global list each time the function is called. This however, is not really a solution in Haskell.

I hope I managed to explain the problem in an understandable manner. I would really appreciate it if somebody could guide me in the right path. So in short, what I need to know is how I can get the new values of (a, b, c) that are computed EACH time the function is called.

Comment: I think your actual problem is combining the results of the recursive call - it's really not possible to tell but probably just [`concat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) `[function () ...]` is all you need

Comment: BTW: why do you need the `()` for the first parameter of that function? Seems obsolete to me.

Comment: PS: you don't include `x` anywhere in your function call - which is probably not what you want - can you give some example of how this function is supposed to work (some input/output pairs)?

Comment: @Carsten I am already using concat. But it only concatenates the list returned on one branch of the recursion (if that makes sense)

Comment: @Carsten () is uset to signify the tuple, it actually contains certain variables in the program. I just left them out

Comment: I'm afraid no - it does not make sense to me - you concat on each call / right now I cannot see what you are trying to do

Comment: @Carsten Ok, so as an example I can give one of the tests I made. In the first turn I get a list of length 8. I call the function on each element but only get 7 tuples back, which correspond to the the length of the list calculated in one of the next 8 calls.

Comment: Could you maybe update your Question with the complete definition of your function together with an sample input and the *expected* output?

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions that "branch out" are commonplace in implementing "divide and conquer" algorithms (e.g. Quicksort). Your problem is that you divide allright, but the conquer step is missing:

```
 | otherwise = [function () a1 b1 c1 | x <- someList]
```

Here you subdivide the problem into a number of subproblems (enumerated by `someList`, and then just return the list of results. Alas, that won't even typecheck: you need to return a result (a list), not a list of results (i.e. a list of lists).

How to combine the results depends on your problem, you need a function with type `[result] -> result` (where `result = [(Int,Int,Int)]` in your specific case). `concat` is such a function, `head` is another (which would indeed make your function only return the numbers computed on one branch of the recursion, like you say it does)